# ImageResizer: web.config AzureReader configuration for cloud/development

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, imageresizer

I'm using ImageResizer (http://imageresizing.net/) and I've configured the AzureReader in the web.config file as follow:

```
<resizer>
  <plugins>
    <add name="AzureReader" 
         connectionString="AzureStorageConnectionString"
         endpoint="<myendopointurl>"
         prefix="images"/>
  </plugins>
</resizer>
```

All works correctly, but because the endpoint changes between the development deploy and the Azure deploy, how can I manage that?
The AzureStorageConnectionString setting is automatically managed (placed in Service Configuration), but if I do the dame think for the endpoing attribute (putting the name of a Service Configuration field), it does not work.
The endpoint attribute should be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/...
```

for local deploys and

```
http://<account>.blob.core.windows.net/...
```

for Azure deploys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With web.config transformations. There is nothing more trivial than that.

Read more [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889).

**UPDATE** (for comment 1)

Image Resizer uses web.config anyway. So you can't go for ServiceConfiguration config file. You can use Cloud Service Configuration file only if Image Resizer has programmatic API for configuration. Then you could use that API to pull out the configuration settings from Cloud Configuration. But what is the issue with web.config transformations anyway? You are going to deploy with Cloud configuration anyway. I don't imagine that you deploy with local config, and just after the service is running you go and change the config in the portal (or using the management API)...

Comment: Right, but transformations does not allow to configure the parameter in Service Configuration directly on Azure. I was looking for an "Azure" aware solution, if any exists.
I suppose that this can be done only if ImageResizer is designed to allow it, but I don't know.

Comment: Ok thanks: I'll search for API availability for configuration. Meanwhile I'm going with Web.config transformation.